# Angular: I have to fetch value from Observable<any> variable without using subscribe method, AIP should not be call again

Tags: javascript, angular

**Angular: I have to fetch value from Observable variable without using subscribe method, AIP should not be call again**

My Code Snippet (Part Of Component Script):

```
....
....
this.serviceVariable.currentProgramStudents = this.serviceVariable.getAllStudents(); //API Call In This Service Function & Need this variable further, could not skip it                

this.serviceVariable.currentProgramStudents.pipe(
    take(1)
).subscribe(students => {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: SET_STUDENTS, payload: students });
});
....
....
```

Working properly, but "take(1)).subscribe" causing API call again, which I want to skip.

I have to get value from that Observable variable without subscribe method or API call.

Please suggest me changes.

Comment: If you have enclosed this snippet in some function and trying to call that function, then it will definitely create new subscriber which will take 1 value from the observable. What you can do is, move the logic to OnInit hook to avoid calling it repeatedly

Comment: What does the getAllStudents method do - is it just using observable for async request/response? It sounds like the Observable isnt working quite right and would probably expect that method to not actually make the API call until something subscribes. Or if it does to maybe replay the item if there are multiple subscribers.

Comment: @AmitChigadani could you please add your solution as answer with my code snippet, yo I can understand